# Why lateral strain occurs when volume is not conserved on applying longitudinal stress?

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain, volume, solid-mechanics

I first thought that lateral strain occurs to conserve volume on applying longitudinal stress but later I realised that I was wrong. But now I have a confusion that why lateral strain occurs if volume is not to be conserved? What is the reason behind lateral strain? Is it intramolecular force or something like that?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a diagram please.

Comment: Useful reading: [Poisson's ratio over two centuries: challenging hypotheses](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3645204/).

Answer (score -1):

The state of stress can be resolved into two linearly superimposed parts:  an isotropic state of stress plus deviation from an isotropic state of stress.  In your example, the isotropic part $\sigma _I$ is $$\sigma_I=\frac{(\sigma_z+\sigma_r+\sigma_{\theta})}{3}$$ and is responsible for volume changes.  The deviatoric part of the stress state is given by $\sigma_z-\sigma_I$, $\sigma_r-\sigma_I$, and $\sigma_{\theta}-\sigma_I$;  the deviatoric part of the stress tensor is responsible for a volume-preserving contribution to the deformation.

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate on the answer I gave, the state of stress for the deformed rod is $$\sigma_z=E\epsilon_z$$$$\sigma_r=0$$$$\sigma_{\theta}=0$$and the strains are $$\epsilon_z=\frac{\sigma_z}{E}$$ $$\epsilon_{r}=-\nu\frac{\sigma_z}{E}$$ $$\epsilon_{r\theta}=-\nu\frac{\sigma_z}{E}$$So the volumetric strain is $$\epsilon=(1-2\nu)\frac{\sigma_a}{E}$$Here, E is Young's modulus and $\nu$ is Poisson's ratio.  The isotropic part of the stress tensor is $$\sigma_I=\frac{\sigma _z}{3}$$The bulk modulus B is equal to the isotropic part of the stress divided by the volumetric strain:  $$B=\frac{E}{3(1-2\nu)}$$